# Get scroll event inside a div angular 2

Tags: html, angular, events, scroll

I'm beginner in angular 2 and i have a problem with a scroll event inside a div. My application has some components sharing a window and most of them has a scroll inside of it, so the problem is that I want to get the scroll event inside of a div of a specific component. I tried to use an Observable but it only gets the scroll events of the window, it does not get event from the wanted component similarly with the `@HostListener("document:scroll", [$event])` behavior. I had tried to use (scroll), but using it the application delays a lot. Does any one has an idea of how can i do this?

Comment: Seems related to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8866. You might want to register outside Angulars zone, so that not each event causes change detection to run.